# GoogleAppsScript - getting Calendar event by id

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

```
function getEventById()
{

   var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();

   var eventseries = cal.getEventSeriesById("0ei62qk010k7m8faua6d0s2pbo@google.com");

   Logger.log(eventseries.getTitle());

   // how to get event from eventseries

   //Logger.log(event.getStartDate());

}
```

I verified [GoogleAppsScirpt for Calendar doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_calendareventseries) but do not find any way to convert CalendarEventSeries to ClaendarEvent object.

Is there any way to do so ?

Comment: Hello Arun, Could you explain you question a little more. All you can do with eventseries object is documented here. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_calendareventseries

Comment: Sorry, missed a part question. Now added !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, currently, there is no such option.
May be you should file a feature request in [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/entry).

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=395 there seems to be existing thread discussing the same so starred it.

Comment: As of Oct. 2017, the Issue cited is now tagged as Fixed. It's now possible to call `getEventById(iCalId)` See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#geteventbyidicalid

Answer (score 0):

This will helps you.

```
function delete_rec_events()
{
  //take care: Date function starts at 0 for the month (January=0)
  var fromDate = new Date(2018,0,1,0,0,0); //This is January 1, 2018
  var toDate = new Date(2018,0,10,0,0,0);   //This is January 10, 2018 at 00h00'00"
  var calendarName = '<Name of the Calendar>';

  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName)[0];
  var events = calendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate);

  for(var i=0; i<events.length;i++)
  {
    var ev = events[i];
    Logger.log('Checking Event Title === ' + calendar.getEventSeriesById(ev.getId()).getTitle());

    calendar.getEventSeriesById(ev.getId()).deleteEventSeries();
    Logger.log('Event Deleted');

  }
}
```